# Ellipses do not align with data using SIBER R package

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian, ellipse

I'm using the `SIBER` package to analyze some data, and am [following this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SIBER/vignettes/Plot-posterior-ellipses.html), but it doesn't seem to be working with my data, and I'm not sure if it's a statistics, coding, or sample size problem (the way I've subdivided my groups, I end up with pretty few datapoints per group). My goal is to produce Bayesian estimates of ellipse dimensions for different combinations of age class, year, and tissue type, but the ellipses I've generated don't seem to align with the data. I've tried increasing the number of iterations and burnin to address any convergence issues, but the ellipses still don't really contain the data. I'm fine with re-grouping my data to answer a different set of questions, but I'd like to confirm that I haven't messed up in a Bayesian or coding way first.

```
library(tidyr)
library(SIBER)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


# First we outline the model parameters as a list
parms <- list()
parms$n.iter <- 10 *10^4
parms$n.burnin <- 2 *10^3
parms$n.thin <- 10
parms$n.chains <- 3

# Then we establish priors
# Inverse wishart on covariance matrix of signma
# Vague normal for means
priors <- list()
priors$R <- 1 * diag(2)
priors$k <- 2
priors$tau.mu <- 1.0E-3

# Here is the dataset
siber_df <- structure(list(iso1 = c(-21.86, -22.57, -22.6, -22, -22.68, -22.48, 
                        -23.09, -21.85, -21.68, -22.19, -22.5, -21.59, -21.92, -22.04, 
                        -22.23, -22.4, -20.79, -20.72, -20.76, -21.16, -22.56, -22.76, 
                        -22.29, -21.91, -21.97, -22.61, -22.73, -21.61, -21.91, -23.58, 
                        -23.36, -22.94, -22.34, -22.71, -21.92, -22.09, -24.37, -21.8, 
                        -22.34, -22.17, -22.54, -22.63, -22.43, -20.63, -22.47, -21.55, 
                        -21.03, -22.19, -24.8, -21.9, -21.83, -21, -21.64, -21.77, -21.39, 
                        -20.39, -21.69, -21.18, -21.28, -22.12, -21.95, -21.29, -21.52, 
                        -21.29, -21.61, -21.61, -22.38, -21.8, -21.72, -22.5, -21.26, 
                        -21.45, -22.39, -22.18, -22.19, -22.48, -22.52, -22.15, -22.04, 
                        -20.81, -20.44, -21.29, -22.04, -22.21, -22.18, -21.96, -21.96, 
                        -21.82, -22.12, -22.55, -22.43, -22.38, -22.07, -22.66, -20.76, 
                        -20.56, -20.65, -22.12, -21.97, -22.105, -22.11, -22.37, -22.48, 
                        -21.32, -21.42, -21.2, -20.72, -21.74, -22.1, -21.5, -21.68, 
                        -21.58, -21.63, -21.43, -22.22, -22.33, -20.49, -20.8, -20.69, 
                        -21.19, -21.52, -22.19, -21.8, -21.24, -21.62, -20.96, -20.79, 
                        -21.665, -21.78, -21.76, -21.58, -21.66, -20.93, -20.935, -21.87, 
                        -21.79, -22.33, -21.01, -21.74, -22.08, -20.43, -21.6, -22.1, 
                        -22.07, -21.67, -21.48, -21.67, -21.64, -21.82, -21.89, -21.35, 
                        -21.3, -21.78, -21.57, -21.89, -21.37, -21.97, -22.12, -22.47, 
                        -22.28, -21.14, -20.58, -20.71, -21.17, -20.97), iso2 = c(7.26, 
                                                                                  5.74, 5.4, 6.57, 5.99, 6.17, 5.96, 8.81, 6.66, 5.54, 5.55, 6.63, 
                                                                                  6.32, 6.71, 6.26, 7.24, 6.08, 6.28, 6.18, 6.02, 7.18, 7.39, 5.89, 
                                                                                  5.12, 7.37, 4.08, 7.12, 7.26, 7.49, 5.36, 5.13, 6.75, 6.19, 5.28, 
                                                                                  7.15, 7.99, 4.35, 7.23, 6.37, 5.81, 6.95, 5.92, 6.17, 7.15, 7.56, 
                                                                                  7.68, 6.97, 6.28, 7.94, 6.58, 5.29, 6.45, 6.47, 6.96, 6.38, 7.85, 
                                                                                  6.42, 5.61, 5.57, 5.19, 5.46, 5.85, 5.82, 6.14, 4.5, 4.34, 6.73, 
                                                                                  6.81, 6.17, 6.87, 7.3, 7.72, 7.7, 2.67, 3.4, 5.29, 4.92, 3.43, 
                                                                                  3.01, 4.95, 5.24, 4.86, 3.21, 2.76, 3.26, 4.61, 4.45, 4.41, 5.44, 
                                                                                  2.72, 4.07, 3.85, 5.37, 2.58, 4.45, 4.96, 5.06, 5.04, 5.03, 3.42, 
                                                                                  3.46, 5.08, 4.98, 6.62, 6.68, 5.38, 5.95, 4.68, 4.37, 3.6, 3.65, 
                                                                                  5.14, 5.03, 4.98, 3.4, 3.59, 5.05, 4.89, 5.07, 6.43, 6.39, 4.67, 
                                                                                  4.84, 6.73, 6.3, 6.41, 6.42, 4.48, 4.13, 5.89, 6.43, 4.8, 6.99, 
                                                                                  6.42, 6.14, 6.19, 5.75, 4.97, 5.91, 5.59, 6.53, 5.52, 6.15, 6.54, 
                                                                                  5.88, 5.38, 5.73, 5.57, 6.09, 5.21, 6.04, 5.88, 5.95, 6.1, 5.87, 
                                                                                  6.01, 5.52, 5.4, 5, 5.3, 6.04, 6.27, 6.33, 6.39, 6.22), group = c("ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "ADULT", "FL", "FL", 
                                                                                                                                                    "FL", "FL", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "HY", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "HY", "HY", "HY", "HY", "HY", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "HY", "ADULT", "FL", 
                                                                                                                                                    "FL", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "FL", "FL", "NL", "NL", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "FL", "FL", 
                                                                                                                                                    "FL", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", "NL", 
                                                                                                                                                    "NL", "ADULT", "ADULT", "FL", "FL", "FL", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "HY", "HY", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", "HY", "HY", 
                                                                                                                                                    "HY", "HY", "HY", "HY", "HY", "HY", "ADULT", "ADULT", "ADULT", 
                                                                                                                                                    "ADULT", "ADULT", "HY", "HY"), community = c("2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2021_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", "2019_feathers", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", "2019_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2019_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", "2021_claws", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2021_claws", "2021_claws")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -165L))


# Converting the whole dataframe into a siber object
siber_object <- createSiberObject(siber_df)

# Calculating group metrics (basically only so I can use the labels for plotting later)
group.ML <- groupMetricsML(siber_object)

# Labeling the ellipses for the model to identify
# These must have periods or they will not be recognized by siber
claws_19_ad <- "2019_claws.ADULT"
claws_19_fl <- "2019_claws.FL"
claws_19_nl <- "2019_claws.NL"
feath_19_ad <- "2019_feathers.ADULT"
feath_19_nl <- "2019_feathers.NL"
feath_19_fl <- "2019_feathers.FL"
claws_21_ad <- "2021_claws.ADULT"
claws_21_hy <- "2021_claws.HY"
feath_21_ad <- "2021_feathers.ADULT"
feath_21_hy <- "2021_feathers.HY"

# Getting a posterior distribution
community_posterior <- siberMVN(siber_object, parms, priors)

SEA.B <- siberEllipses(community_posterior)

siberDensityPlot(SEA.B, xticklabels = colnames(group.ML), 
                 xlab = c("Community | Group"),
                 ylab = expression("Standard Ellipse Area " ('permille' ^2) ),
                 bty = "L",
                 las = 1,
                 main = "SIBER ellipses on each group"
)

# how many of the posterior draws do you want?
n.posts <- 10

# decide how big an ellipse you want to draw
p.ell <- 0.95

# for a standard ellipse use
# p.ell <- pchisq(1,2)




# a list to store the results
all_ellipses <- list()

# loop over groups
for (i in 1:length(community_posterior)){
  
  # a dummy variable to build in the loop
  ell <- NULL
  post.id <- NULL
  
  for ( j in 1:n.posts){
    
    # covariance matrix
    Sigma  <- matrix(community_posterior[[i]][j,1:4], 2, 2)
    
    # mean
    mu     <- community_posterior[[i]][j,5:6]
    
    # ellipse points
    
    out <- ellipse::ellipse(Sigma, centre = mu , level = p.ell)
    
    
    ell <- rbind(ell, out)
    post.id <- c(post.id, rep(j, nrow(out)))
    
  }
  ell <- as.data.frame(ell)
  ell$rep <- post.id
  all_ellipses[[i]] <- ell
}

ellipse_df <- bind_rows(all_ellipses, .id = "id")


# now we need the group and community names

# extract them from the community_posterior list
group_comm_names <- names(community_posterior)[as.numeric(ellipse_df$id)]

# split them and conver to a matrix, NB byrow = T
split_group_comm <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(group_comm_names, "[.]")),
                           nrow(ellipse_df), 2, byrow = TRUE)

ellipse_df$community <- split_group_comm[,1]
ellipse_df$group     <- split_group_comm[,2]

ellipse_df <- dplyr::rename(ellipse_df, iso1 = x, iso2 = y)


first.plot <- ggplot(data = siber_df, aes(iso1, iso2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(group):factor(community)), size = 2)+
  ylab(expression(paste(delta^{15}, "N (permille)")))+
  xlab(expression(paste(delta^{13}, "C (permille)"))) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
print(first.plot)

second.plot <- first.plot + facet_wrap(~factor(group):factor(community))
print(second.plot)

third.plot <- second.plot + 
  geom_polygon(data = ellipse_df,
               mapping = aes(iso1, iso2,
                             group = rep,
                             color = factor(group):factor(community),
                             fill = NULL),
               fill = NA,
               alpha = 0.2)
print(third.plot)
```